# replace all occurence of regex does not work

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var temp = '<p class="fasfasfasd">Type <strong>Markdown</strong> here. {:.fasfasfasd}</p>'+
                '<p class="fdfsdf">fdsfsdf {:.fdfsdf}</p>'
//this should match everything like {:*}
var re = /\{:(.*?)\}/;
console.log(temp);
temp = temp.replace(re, "", 'gm');
console.log(temp);
```

Here a running example:  http://jsfiddle.net/AL8DN/

I want to delete all occurences of the regex re in the string temp. However the second match of the regex is never deleted. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Mozilla developer reference:

> The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is
>   non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object
>   with the corresponding flags

So, by changing this to:

```
var temp = '<p class="fasfasfasd">Type <strong>Markdown</strong> here. {:.fasfasfasd}</p>'+
                '<p class="fdfsdf">fdsfsdf {:.fdfsdf}</p>'
var re = /\{:(.*?)\}/gm;
console.log(temp);
temp = temp.replace(re, "");
console.log(temp);
```

It seems to work correctly.

Comment: I think the String.replace third parameter is enforced if the first parameter is a string, not a reg ex (NEED verification).

Comment: @Eineki That would make sense. If both the regex and the replace() arguments contain two different sets of flags, it would be unclear to the browser which one to use. With a string, there would be no ambiguity.